# phpUnit in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

I would want to have some of the pros help.
Well, I've been trying to set up the phpunit in netbeans but cannot run the tests.
Whenever I run the tests the error shows up and cannot run the tests

indexTest.php

```
    <?php
class indexTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // ...

    public function testCanBeNegated()
    {
        // Arrange
        $a = new index(1);

        // Act
        $b = $a->negate();

        // Assert
        $this->assertEquals(-1, $b->getAmount());
    }

    // ...
}
```

index.php

```
    <?php
class index
{
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function negate()
    {
        return new index(-1 * $this->amount);
    }

    // ...
}
```

for example, how will I test the codes like these?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What error is it that is showing?

Comment: You have to reference you class file in test script. So put require 'path/index.php' in your 'indexTest.php' file.